# Partial limit of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If the sequences $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$ satisfy for all $n, m$ the inequality $$a_{n} \leqslant b_{m}$$
and $x$ is a partial limit of $a_{n}$, $y$ is a partial limit of $b_{n}$; then

$$x \leqslant y$$

Is the statement right or wrong? Can somebody provide a clue to prove or disprove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $a_n \le b_m$ for all $n$ and $m$, we have $\limsup a_n \le b_m$ for all $m$. Hence $\limsup a_n \le \liminf b_n$. So the statement is true.